# how to get the value from the controller to the view in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

```
{{(URL('default', 'test', args=[textname[i],"1","english"]))}}
```

I am having this line of code in view to send the values to the controller function called `test()`

In `test()`, I do some operations and return a string. I need to display the string in the view. How to get the string from controller in the same view again?

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting your question correctly, you want to display return vars of your controller into the html.

From the controller you can return a response object:

```
return render_to_response('url_for_your_view',{'var1': 'your string goes here'}, RequestContext(request))
```

And in the view then you can display the string as `{{var1}}`.

Comment: The question asks about web2py, but the above appears to be Django code. This won't work in web2py (and I don't think it's quite right in Django either -- I believe the first argument should be the name of a template, not a URL).

Comment: return render_to_response('tamil.html',{'var1':messag }, RequestContext(request))       is it correct??? in view i am getting var1 not defined

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the output of one action within the page of another action, you should use the [`LOAD()` helper](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/12#Components) to create a component:

```
{{=LOAD('default', 'test.load', args=[textname[i], "1", "english"], ajax=True)}}
```

Note, with `ajax=True`, the component will be loaded via Ajax after the parent page loads. If you set `ajax=False` (which is the default), then the component will be inserted server-side when the parent page is first created.

In the default.py controller, you then have:

```
def test():
    textname, number, language = tuple(request.args)
    result = [do something with the request.args values]
    return result
```

The value of `result` will then be inserted in a `<div>` in place of `{{=LOAD(...)}}`.

Comment: wat should be my controller return statement?? how ll i get the value from controller??

Comment: See updated answer. If that's not enough, then I suggest you post a question on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/web2py), as it is not quite clear what you are trying to do and it may take some discussion to resolve.